# Supermicro Motherboard won't boot, onboard power LED lights up

Tags: hardware, boot, supermicro

I'm having issues getting a Supermicro motherboard to boot. When I switch the PSU on, the Onboard Standby Power LED lights up on the motherboard. Pushing the power switch then has no effect. No beeps, nothing on the screen, the PSU fan doesn't start and no motherboard fans turn at all.

I can't see any damage or blown capacitors. I've covered a lot of the obvious things already -:

- Unplugged all drives, expansion boards and peripherals. Testing only with CPUs and RAM.
- Tested with 2 different EPS PSUs, both known to be working elsewhere.
- All 6 4-pin PWM fan headers have a 4-pin PWM fan connected.
- Replaced CR2032 CMOS battery with brand new one.
- Remounted with additional paper washers to ensure no short circuit.
- Removed all DIMMs and tested with no RAM as well as just 1 stick and 2 sticks.

The board is an X7DCA-L-YI001 https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5100/X7DCA-L.cfm

The manual I am using is available from the link above.

This motherboard is originally intended for use in one of Supermicro's own cases with their own power supply. I am attempting to mount it in a third-party rackmount case, using a standard EPS PSU.

Is there some detail that I am missing that could be the reason?

Any questions or suggestions welcomed, thanks.

Comment: Did you try powering on using a conductible metal, such a screwdriver to touch the power-on motherboard pins manually instead of using the power button? Long shot I know, but I've seen it happen

Comment: Yes I did try that. Good point though, it could be a faulty switch, unlikely but possible. But yes, I tried that too.